# Xamarin Forms: backgroundImage from external storage

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, storage

I am developing a `Xamarin Form`s which writes successfully an image to external storage and then should use it as Background of a ContentPage.

In the constructor of the ContentPage I wrote this:

```
this.BackgroundImage = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/D72D01AEF71348CDBFEED9D0B2F259F7.jpg"
```

but the background image never shows.

I checked the Android Manifest and the permissions of read and write external storage are set correctly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `BackgroundImage` expects an image that's bundled with your app. Android implementation for updating the background image is here:

```
void UpdateBackgroundImage(Page view)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(view.BackgroundImage))
        this.SetBackground(Context.Resources.GetDrawable(view.BackgroundImage));
}
```

`GetDrawable` method expects an image from your application's Resources which obviously doesn't exist in your case.

What you should do, is create a custom renderer with a new BindableProperty called ExternalBackgroundImage. Then you could handle loading of the external image as a background in the Android specific custom renderer.

**PCL project**

Remember to change your current page from `ContentPage` to `ExternalBackgroundImagePage` so that you have access to the `ExternalBackgroundImage` property.

```
public class ExternalBackgroundImagePage : ContentPage 
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ExternalBackgroundImageProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ExternalBackgroundImage", typeof(string), typeof(Page), default(string));

    public string ExternalBackgroundImage
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ExternalBackgroundImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ExternalBackgroundImageProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Android project**

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(ExternalBackgroundImagePage), typeof(ExternalBackgroundImagePageRenderer))]
namespace YourProject.Droid
{
    public class ExternalBackgroundImagePageRenderer : PageRenderer 
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            Page view = e.NewElement;
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            UpdateExternalBackgroundImage(view);
        }

        void UpdateExternalBackgroundImage(Page view)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(view.ExternalBackgroundImage)) 
              return;   

            // Retrieve a bitmap from a file
            var background = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(view.ExternalBackgroundImage);  

            // Convert to BitmapDrawable for the SetBackground method
            var bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(background);

            // Set the background image
            this.SetBackground(bitmapDrawable);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
this.ExternalBackgroundImage = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/D72D01AEF71348CDBFEED9D0B2F259F7.jpg"
```